# Why do the dividers in the iOS settings page not go all the way to the left?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, ios

The designers at Apple seem to have made a deliberate decision to make the dividers in the iOS settings page not span the full width of the screen.

[image: iOS settings page]

What makes this better than full width dividers?

[image: Edited to make dividers go all the way]

Comment: You'd better circle the spot that dividers not continue till the end. The grey spot or any other parts of the UI can be understood as divider in this case and it takes almost a minute to understand which divider you mention

Answer (score 1):

The grey blocks, which span the full width, group certain settings together, for example *About* and *Software Update*.

*Indenting* the divider line between these two items, so to speak, makes it clear that the line seperates two items, but not groups.

Think of nested lists:

- Group 1

  - About
  - Software Update
- Group 2

These, too, commonly use *both* indentation and a different item marker for each level.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a design decision specific to the Settings app. But rather, that is how [table views in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/) have been implemented.

The dividers that are indented to the right are simply so to demarcate that the line items that follow the divider are of the same series of records as the ones above the divider.

At best it is to provide some emphasis on the [law of common region](https://lawsofux.com/law-of-common-region.html)... or just a mere visual design gimmick.

The dividers are usually offset by the same amount as the record label. For example, with an icon in the table record, the offset would become `15px + (width of the icon) + 15px @1x`. Whereas, if there is no icon, the record offset is just `15px @1x`.